# How to convert Dao object to Model in Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, orm, kotlin-exposed

I am using Jetbrains `Exposed` library to create ORMs for my entities.

I have an entity `Book` which has a one-to-one mapping with `Author` entity and one-to-many mapping to `Chapter` entity.

Using exposeds DAO classes I have created the below ORM mappings between the entities which succesfully returns a `BookDao` object. The problem is that I need to convert this to type `BookModel` so it can be serialized and sent back to the client.

How can I convert the `book` object (of type BookDao) to type BookModel? I have looked through Exposed's [documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO) but do not see a way of doing this.

```kotlin
val bookDao = BookDao.findById(1)?.load(BookDao::author, BookDao::chapters)
***logic to convert BookDao to BookModel***
call.respond(bookModel)

object Books: IntIdTable()

class BookDao(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<BookDao>(Books)
    val author by AuthorDao referrersOn Authors.book
    val chapters by ChapterDao referrersOn Chapters.book
}

object Authors : IntIdTable() {
    val firstName = varchar("firstName", 32)
    val lastName = varchar("lastName", 32)
    val book = reference("book", Books)
}
class AuthorDao (id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<AuthorDao>(Authors)
    var firstName by Authors.firstName
    var lastName by Authors.lastName
    var book by BookDao referencedOn Authors.book
}


object Chapters: IntIdTable() {
    val title = varchar("title", 512)
    val book = reference("book", Books)
}
class ChapterDao(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object: IntEntityClass<ChapterDao>(Chapters)
    var title by Chapters.title
    var book by BookDao referencedOn Chapters.book
}

@Serializable
data class BookModel(
    val author: AuthorModel,
    val chapters: List<ChapterModel>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `author` should be `authors` because is a 1 to N relationship

You have to do it manually, you can define a function to convert each dao to model.

Given this models

```kotlin
data class BookModel(
    val authors: List<AuthorModel>,
    val chapters: List<ChapterModel>
)

data class AuthorModel(
    val firstName : String,
    val lastName: String
)

data class ChapterModel(
    val title : String
)
```

Define this functions to convert to models

```kotlin
class BookDao(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<BookDao>(Books)
    val authors by AuthorDao referrersOn Authors.book
    val chapters by ChapterDao referrersOn Chapters.book
    
    fun toModel() = BookModel(
        authors = authors.map { it.toModel() },
        chapters = chapters.map { it.toModel() }
    )
}

class AuthorDao (id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<AuthorDao>(Authors)
    var firstName by Authors.firstName
    var lastName by Authors.lastName
    var book by BookDao referencedOn Authors.book

    fun toModel() = AuthorModel(
        firstName = firstName,
        lastName = lastName
    )
}

class ChapterDao(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object: IntEntityClass<ChapterDao>(Chapters)
    var title by Chapters.title
    var book by BookDao referencedOn Chapters.book

    fun toModel() = ChapterModel(
        title = title
    )
}
```

Then just use

```kotlin
val bookDao = BookDao.findById(1)?.load(BookDao::author, BookDao::chapters)
val bookModel = bookDao.toModel()
call.respond(bookModel)
```

Be careful with the N+1 problem, I recommend use DSL instead of DAO